# Sprite and its body don't act the same way to forces

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

So I created a body and filled it with a sprite. The problem is that if I apply a force on the body, the sprite goes higher than the body (which I can see from debug_draw). Any idea why this is happening?

**UPDATE**

```
- (void)tick:(ccTime) dt {

    _world->Step(dt, 10, 10);

    for(b2Body *b = _world->GetBodyList(); b; b=b->GetNext()) {    
        if (b->GetUserData() != NULL) {
            CCSprite *playerData = (CCSprite *)b->GetUserData();
            playerData.position = ccp(b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO,
                                    b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO);
            playerData.rotation = -1 * CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(b->GetAngle());
        }        
    }

}
```

And here's how I call this in my init method:

```
[self schedule:@selector(tick:)];
```

Comment: Does it get progressively worse as you move away further?  Or is the offset a relatively small static distance?

Comment: how frequently are you synchronizing the b2Body position with your cocos2d sprite position? some code would be useful.

Comment: @Jon It gets progressively worse.

Comment: Your posted code looks good as far as I can tell. Do the sprite and body shape start off being aligned in the first place? Show the code where you setup your body and the sprite.

Comment: @kennot at first they didn't, so I changed the anchor point of my sprite, and I think that's what led to this problem. But if I don't set the anchor point, the sprite is not aligned with the body. I can't seem to fix this problem, please help.

Comment: Please see if my suggestion on your original post helps.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop which gets the User_Data is kept on repeating now and then so to update the position of the creature would be difficult.. Please move the sprites position in the tick method....

```
-(void) moveCreature
{
    // Please use the position to set the directions. This is used to fall from upside down in Portrait mode
    [spriteCreature setPosition:ccp(spriteCreature.position.x,spriteCreature.position.y-5)];

}
```

Now in the init method schedule the sprite

```
-(id) init
{
    if((self = [super init])) 
    {
        // Create your World and other stuffs 
        [self schedule:@selector(moveCreature)];

    }
return self;
}
```

The above stuff would carry the sprite in the body n fall down...